# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'd' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to access a variable from static method to outside.

```
class Hello():

   def __init__(self, a, b):
     self.a = a
     self.b = b
     self.c = 0

   @staticmethod
   def add():
     d = 10

   print("hello", d)
```

How to access variable 'd' in outside of static method?

Comment: But why would u need this, you could simply do:

Comment: class Hello():
   global d
   def __init__(self, a, b):
     self.a = a
     self.b = b
     self.c = 0

   def add():
     d = 10

   print("hello", d)

Comment: Secondly, why do u need to print(d) if u can do outside of class?><

Comment: @imsr: Please don't do this, it will bite you at some point.

Comment: I am trying to modify the someone's code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need `@staticmethod` for just `d = 10`. You can assign it outside of the constructor (as mentioned below). And then to access that variable, you can try, `CLASS_NAME.VARIABLE_NAME`.

```
class Hello():
  d = 10
  def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.c = 0


print("hello", Hello.d)
```